# Calling Window.scrollTo() on Android Mobile Browser causes TypeError: No function was found that matched the signature provided

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, browser, cross-browser

I have a React Project - I'm attaching an `onClick` to the Header Navigation Links that scroll to a particular element on the page. I am generating React refs, and using the Y position of the elements to input into a `Window.scrollTo()` function call.

Here is the code:

```
class Component extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.menuRef = React.createRef()
    }

    scrollToRef(ref, instructions, event, arg2) {
        if (event) event.preventDefault()

        let pageOffSet = 200

            if (this.state.topOfPage) {
                pageOffSet = 200 
            } else if (!this.state.topOfPage) {
                pageOffSet = 150
            }

            window.scrollTo({top: (ref.current.offsetTop - pageOffSet), behavior: "smooth"})
    }

    render(){return(
     // Pseudocode...
    <button onClick={() => this.scrollToRef(this.menunRef, "contact", event)}
    <div ref={this.menuRef}/>
    )}
}
```

Expected Behavior: 
Window scrolls down to ref Y coordinates, react state changes according to "instructions" recieved by function (I omitted setState calls)
Actual Behavior:
Working in most browsers.
In default Android browser, I get the following error:
[image]

Component Full Code on Github: https://github.com/Mikhail-MM/wsd-dental/blob/master/src/components/TabletSite.js

Working Demo: https://worldsmilesdental.herokuapp.com/

Please help, I am at my wits end trying to debug this. I have no idea how to debug mobile browsers, How can I see the output of `console.log()` on a mobile safari or android browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That’s a new-ish signature for `scrollTo`, it used to only accept `scrollTo( x, y )` but now it can also accept an object. The android browser must not know about the new version. You can use a [polyfill](https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll) to patch it.

if you have a Mac you can debug iOS Safari through desktop Safari: https://appletoolbox.com/2014/05/use-web-inspector-debug-mobile-safari/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The SmoothScroll polyfill fixed up the crash indeed. Unfortunately I do not have a Mac. Is there any way to debug the Samsung Browser, that you are aware of?