# Is there a difference between using window.scrollTo({top: 50}) over window.scrollTo(0, 50)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently using `window.scrollTo({top: 50})` in a React function, which works perfectly.

However, passing an object to `window.scrollTo` is not supported on older versions of Android (there's a [question with the details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912563/calling-window-scrollto-on-android-mobile-browser-causes-typeerror-no-functio)).

I've switch to using `window.scrollTo(0, 50)`, which is performing exactly as I need (scrolling to the top with a 50px offset). I've tested this in multiple browsers and it seems to be working correctly.

Is there any downside to using an X-Y coordinates in this way vs. providing an object with a `top` field? I had a look on MDN, but there's no info comparing the two methods.

Comment: [CanIUse](https://www.caniuse.com/?search=scrollto) has data on the support of various `scrollTo` options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scrollTo({top: 50})` will leave the horizontal scroll unchanged, but `scrollTo(0, 50)` will set both the horizontal and vertical scroll. If you want the horizontal scroll also changed, you're good. Otherwise, you'll need to use `scrollTo(window.scrollX, 50)`.

Here's an example showing that `scrollTo({top: 50})` doesn't change the horizontal scroll:

```js
const marker = Array.from(Array(26), (_, i) => String.fromCharCode(97 + (i % 26)) + " ").join("");
let text = "";
for (let y = 1; y <= 200; ++y) {
    text += marker.substring(0, y * 2) + "\n";
}
document.querySelector(".x").innerText = text;
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Scrolling to 100, 100");
    window.scrollTo(20, 100);
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Scrolling to {top: 50}");
        window.scrollTo({top: 50});
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`window.scrollX = ${window.scrollX}`);
        }, 100);
    }, 800);
}, 800);
```

```css
.x {
    width: 2000px;
    height: 2000px;
    white-space: pre;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="x"></div>
```

...but `scrollTo(0, 50)` does:

```js
const marker = Array.from(Array(26), (_, i) => String.fromCharCode(97 + (i % 26)) + " ").join("");
let text = "";
for (let y = 1; y <= 200; ++y) {
    text += marker.substring(0, y * 2) + "\n";
}
document.querySelector(".x").innerText = text;
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Scrolling to 100, 100");
    window.scrollTo(20, 100);
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Scrolling to 0, 50");
        window.scrollTo(0, 50);
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`window.scrollX = ${window.scrollX}`);
        }, 100);
    }, 800);
}, 800);
```

```css
.x {
    width: 2000px;
    height: 2000px;
    white-space: pre;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="x"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate! That's exactly what I was hoping to confirm.